# How to automate function for all the files in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have two C++ codes and more than a thousand files to be inputs there. I would like to automate this in bash.
For now I have

```
#!/bin/bash
for each in find \data -iname '*.dat';
do ./ppd $file;  
   ./porenet $file;
done
```

As an experiment I put two .dat files in folder, not thousand. But it only applying first function to both .dat files. The second (porenet) is applied only to the first .dat file.
What do I need to change so it will work?
Thanks

Comment: `$file` isn't set. `\data` is the same as `data`. Your loop iterates over four strings, `find`, `data`, `-iname`, and `*.dat`.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus, I corrected it as this service advised, and now it doesn't work at all

Comment: Are your files all in one directory? Or are some in subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question means you want to run `ppd` and then `porenet` on all the `*.dat` files. If so, you can probably do them easily in parallel like this with **GNU Parallel**:

```
find . -name \*.dat -print0 | parallel --dry-run -0 './ppd {}; ./porenet {}'
```

If the output looks like what you want, remove the `--dry-run` and run it again for real.

**Make a backup first, please.**